# Why in_array function return TRUE when we are looking for an empty string?

Tags: php

Could someone explain to me why that is true?

```
in_array('', array(0,1,2));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because, as said in the [**docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

> `bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )`
>
> Searches **haystack** for **needle** using loose comparison unless **strict** is set.

... and `'' == 0` is [**true**](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) in PHP. If you want to use strict comparison, just call `in_array()` with three params:

```
in_array('', array(0, 1, 2), true); // false
```

... so the types will be checked as well, and String `''` won't have a chance to match against Numbers.

Comment: Worth including this table as well: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose

Answer (score 2):

`in_array` by default performs loose comparison. Thus `''` is equivalent to `0`.

There is third argument (boolean) to `in_array` function which says if the matching is to be performed in STRICT way or not.

if you do `in_array('', array(0,1,2), TRUE);` then the result will be false.

Refer the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)